# Compile Error, Member is not a member of a union | working with pointers/structs

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

I have rewritten a function i need for a project to build a database of medias with information on the media itself.
In the following piece of code im trying to obtain a string from a user with the format HH:MM:SS for the length of the title. 
I then have to split the string using pointers to the first isdigit char for hours, first isdigit char after first ":" for minutes and first isdigit char after last ":" to check if the strings are ok with what i want the user to enter. 
For checking if the substring is legit i then convert to int with atoi and try to write back into the structs, but the pointers are toasting me.
Any help is appreciated.

Heres the code itself (pastebin for better readability) [datetime.c with functions to examine string and put pointers on first digit of the input, first digit after first: and first digit after last:](http://pastebin.com/gYcvjMef)

i commented where the compile errors occur (l.103 105 107 on the pastebin)

For better insights here are the structs im using:

[datastructure.h everything but char * zeit is required as written](http://pastebin.com/0bmdTHec)

Thx in advance i am really feeling stupid lately trying to force it to compile via trial and error and i don't think I'm getting closer to the destination at all...

Edit: When im trying to compile:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Iue2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users[...]\datetime.c||In function 'convertStringToTime':|
C:\Users[...]\datetime.c|104|error: request for member 'hour' in something not a structure or union|
C:\Users[...]\datetime.c|106|error: request for member 'minute' in something not a structure or union|
C:\Users[...]1\datetime.c|108|error: request for member 'second' in something not a structure or union|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Using [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) you can do both validation and conversion at the same time.

Comment: As for your problem, *what* errors do you get? Please *edit your question* to include the complete and unedited error log.

Comment: updated. Sorry i thought adding it to the lines and refer to it is ok.

Comment: ok i found my mistake just by reading it in the pastebin style now. instead of *lp i passed *zeit to convertStringToTime. Man i can't believe i always read over it in the past 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

line 74 was corrupted: instead of void convertStringToTime(char * strTime , TTime * Zeit) it had to be void convertStringToTime(char * strTime , TTime * lp). anything else seems to be fine. 
Will try to get the memory allocation done now and look at strtol() as an alternative solution.